# Linq query to check for duplicate values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

In one of my pages I need to check if the entered information about a customer consists duplicate `PAN NO,Email,Mobile No` which may have been entered previously.Currently I am trying it using this `Linq To SQL` statement

```
    var duplicate = (from dup in dt.Data_Customer_Logs
                     where dup.cPanGirNo == panno 
                           || dup.cEmail == email 
                           || dup.nMobileNo.ToString() == mobno
    select dup).Any();
```

It is working but can anyone help me as to what is the correct method to solve my issue.Also if there are no records found what would be the result.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I tried by passing duplicate email id but it didnot execute the "if records found" part.

Comment: it should work, but there could be issues related to case or leading/trailing spaces

Comment: @ie Maybe I need to check that ,also what if there are no records found , will it throw exception or just return null.

Comment: anyway, you should debug the code and find out what is wrong with the where part

Comment: @freebird Any returns `true/false`

Comment: @ie Thanks a lot , is it a good way to do what I am trying to do , can you suggest me some alternatives.Thanks.

Comment: so you entered existing values for `panno`, `email`, and `mobno` and the query returned `false`?

Comment: @freebird the best way - profile the DB and find out what exactly executing on the server side and find our what is wrong there

Comment: @RoboLover It is actually returning true , so it worked.Do you think it is a good way for my purpose.Any good alternatives.thanks.

Comment: I can't say it is the best as my motto is that there might always be a better way for solving a problem, but I see no problem to worry about your code and it actually looks okay to me.

Comment: @RoboLover I agree that there re always better way to solve issues.Thanks for the suggestion.Thanks.

Comment: how are variables panno, email and mobno defined?

Comment: They are textbox values which are passed as arguments to the function where I use this query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool duplicateExists = dt.Data_Customer_Logs.Any(x => 
                         x.cPanGirNo == panno 
                      || x.cEmail == email
                      || x.nMobileNo.ToString() == mobno);
```

This is a tad cleaner if you just want to know if such records exist or not.  And I think it will avoid bringing back multiple records to the client side *and then* doing `IEnumerable<T>.Any` on the results.

If you need to also get back the records that match the criteria, you can use `IQueryable<T>.Where`:

```
var duplicates =  dt.Data_Customer_Logs.Where(x => 
                         x.cPanGirNo == panno 
                      || x.cEmail == email
                      || x.nMobileNo.ToString() == mobno);
if(duplicates.Any())
{
    // use duplicates...
    foreach(var dup in duplicates)
    {
        //use dup.cEmail, dup.nMobileNo, etc.
```

Comment: I have not used lambda expressions before , could you explain me a bit about the query you used.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure. Everything in `Any` is a lambda expression. The lambda expression here serves as a function like `bool myFunction<T>(T x)`. We don't have to explicitly specify the type of `x` (T) thanks to the type inference feature of C#.

Comment: Also If I find records how do I get them , I mean how to use IEnumerable for getting results , a small example will be good enough for me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: the updated answer can be used if bool duplicateExists is true right.

Comment: @freebird no, you would use the second code _instead of_ the first one. If you just need to know whether duplicates exist or not, use the first one. If you need to retrieve the duplicate records (which also tells you whether duplicates exist or not) then use the second one.

Comment: Thanks a lot got it , accepting your answer.Thanks mate.Last help , how do I iterate using duplicates , sorry but I have very little experience with this.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @freebird see the update. nothing special about it, just use a foreach.

Comment: Perfect , thanks a bit more research from my end will make things easier.thanks forthe help.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var duplicate = (from dup in dt.Data_Customer_Logs
                 where dup.cPanGirNo == panno 
                       || dup.cEmail == email 
                       || dup.nMobileNo.ToString() == mobno
select dup).FirstOrDefault();

if(duplicate != null && duplicate.Any())
   //here logic of what should happend if there is something in db
```

Comment: Ok so you are suggesting me to check firstly if it is null or not and then use Any() , can I get all the records found.Thanks.

Comment: you should check first null always it's good practice to avoid NullReferenceException

Comment: But Any() returns true or false , so if it is null will it throw an exception.Not sure.

Comment: The check on Any() is useless. If it doesn't find any match it will return null, if it finds a match it returns only the first occurrence...

Comment: @freebird If the first part of the `&&` evaluates to false, the second part doesn't even get evaluated.

Comment: @Rawling So using only Any() is better , right as it will return true if found or false.

Comment: @freebird In this case, `duplicate` is a single item (or null) rather than an enumeration, so you should _only_ do the null check. In general, the `x != null && x.SomeProperty...` pattern is a good one if you're worried `x` may be null. It's just that, here, the `Any` part makes no sense.